# Laravel how to get posts by different columns?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get a list of posts by the following principle:

Get by post creation date `created_at`. But if `post_top_date` is not equal to the steering wheel, take the date from this column. This is the date of raising the post above all.

`post_top_date` = dateTime column

This method is currently being used. But it doesn't work correctly.

```
PostModel::where('status', 1)
    ->where('moderation','=', 0)
    ->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)
    ->orderBy('created_at')->paginate($ElPerPageCategory);
```

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257590/order-by-2-conditions-on-query-eloquent

Comment: @Neowaring, are you able to retrieve the data you want using SQL? If so, could you post that please?